# MVC3 Tutorial HtmlHelper not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm having a problem with the MVC3 MusicStore tutorial. It defines an HtmlHelper with a Truncate method. The helper looks like this:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MusicStore.Helpers
{
    public class HtmlHelpers
    {
        public static string Truncate(this HtmlHelper helper, string input, int length)
        {
            if (input.Length <= length)
            {
                return input;
            }
            else
            {
                return input.Substring(0, length) + "...";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the view, I import it using `@using MusicStore.Helpers`, and then try to use it with `<td>@Html.Truncate(item.Title, 25) </td>`

However the compiler tells me no such method (Truncate) exists, and seems to be looking for Truncate on IEnumerable[MvcMusicStore.Models.Album] (which is my model) rather than on my HtmlHelpers class.

(NB the square brackets above are really angled brackets in my code, couldnt escape them)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 9):

Extension methods should be declared in a static class:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static string Truncate(
        this HtmlHelper helper, 
        string input, 
        int length
    )
    {
        if (input.Length <= length)
        {
            return input;
        }
        return input.Substring(0, length) + "...";
    }
}
```

and then in your view make sure you have referenced the namespace containing the static class with the extension method:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
...
<td>@Html.Truncate(item.Title, 25)</td>
```

or if you want the helper to be available in all Razor views without the need of adding a using directive you could add the corresponding namespace to the namespaces section of `~/Views/web.config` file:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Namespace.Containig.Static.Class.With.Custom.Helpers" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: +1, and Side note - i've seen uses of `IHtmlString` in MVC3 for HTML Helpers. Should we be using that in MVC3? I'm not sure what other classes implement this interface. Or is it for unit testing (mocking) that we do this?

Comment: @RPM1984, yes you could use `IHtmlString` as return type. It would be more correct. And it's not for unit testing as here it is as return type so we don't care about mocking it, it's just about good practices to use the class/interface which is higher in the hierarchy.

Comment: **Don't return IHtmlString**.  That's not HTML, and must be escaped.

Comment: @SLaks - clarification please?

Comment: @SLaks, it doesn't make any difference. `MvcHtmlString` implements `IHtmlString` and in both case you must HTML encode the returned string **inside** the helper. For example `return MvcHtmlString.Create("<abc>")` is bad no matter whether your return type is `IHtmlString` or `MvcHtmlString`.

Comment: @Darin: Which you aren't doing.  It's easier to let Razor escape it.

Comment: @RPM: Only return IHtmlString if you're returning actual (escaped) HTML.

Comment: @Slaks, that's true, in this case returning `string` would be better. I will update my answer.

Comment: So does Razor escape a result of type 'string' but not IHtmlString or MvcHtmlString?

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods must be defined in a static class. So change you code to:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static string Truncate(this HtmlHelper helper, string input, int length)
    {
        if (input.Length <= length)
        {
            return input;
        }
        else
        {
            return input.Substring(0, length) + "...";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, @Darin Dimitrov brings up a good point - you should really retrun an instance of `MvcHtmlString`.

On a related note, you can import namespaces into your views through the web.config - I'd recommend doing that so you don't have to remember to do it in every page.

Comment: Ahh, thanks to you both (very quick too!). The complete solution in the tutorial seems a bit broken then. First, I forgot to make my class static (oops) and also changing it to return an MvcHtmlString helped too. The number of args is correct though, although I have to admit I dont quite understand the args syntax (this HtmlHelper helper) since I don't need to specify that when I actually use it in my View but I guess it's something the framework passes in automatically?

Comment: Exactly... it's called an "Extension Method" - see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method

Comment: **Don't return IHtmlString**.  That's not HTML, and must be escaped.

Comment: Blimey lots of replies now! Thanks for all these tips everyone, have bookmarked this question as I think I'll be referring to it as I progress!

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider adding the namespace to your web.config. I know I use my helpers on multiple pages. Remembering to add `using` on every view is a pain.

```
<system.web>
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="MusicStore.Helpers"/>
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```